# Credit Analysis - Mean, Variance, Deviation

Tags: probability, statistics

In order to reduce risks, banks investigate how many credit cards a possible client have.

Consider $X$ as the number of credit cards the client have:

---

$$\begin{array}{l|r}
\text{ }  X & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\hline
P(x) & 0.26 & 0.16 & 0.12 & 0.09 & 0.07 & 0.09 & 0.07 & 0.14 
\end{array}$$

---

a) Can this distribution be considered as probability distribution? Why?

b) If you answered yes, calculate: Mean, Variance and Standard Deviation for the number of $X$ credit cards.

Comment: What characteristics must $P$ have in order to be a probability distribution? Of course, the entire question is pretty easy if the answer to (a) is no. So, just in case $P$ *is* a probability distribution: How do you define mean, variance and so forth?

Comment: @dmk, I really don't know. Don't remember how to calculate those. I thought that "P" should be linear, constant, but it goes from 0.09 to 0.07 then 0.09 again...

Comment: Does your textbook define any of these terms?

Comment: No. I found it, personally, confusing, I would say the expected answer is "yes" for the first one, but couldn't answer "why"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a probability distribution since $P[X = i] \geq 0, i = 0, 1, \ldots, 7$ and $\sum_{i = 0}^7 P[X = i] = 1$. More specifically, $X$ is a **discrete** random variable and the probability distribution presented in the table is known as the **probability mass function** (in abbreviation, the **pmf**).

Given the pmf of $X$, there are formulas to calculate the $k$th **moment** of $X$ as follows:
$$E[X^k] = \sum_i i^k P[X = i], \tag{*}$$
where $i$ ranges over the values that $X$ can take. In your case, the summation is over $0$ to $7$.

In particular, the **expectation** is defined to be $E[X]$ --- the first moment, and the variance $\text{Var}[X]$ is defined to be $\text{Var}[X] = E[X^2] - \{E[X]\}^2$. The standard deviation is the arithmetic square root of $\text{Var}[X]$.

Given this background, I am sure you can complete the calculation by yourself for your concrete example.

---

More details:
Apply $(*)$ for $k = 1$, we have
\begin{align}
& E[X] \\
= & 0 \times 0.26 + 1 \times 0.16 + 2 \times 0.12 + 3 \times 0.09 + 4 \times 0.07 + 5 \times 0.09 + 6 \times 0.07 + 7 \times 0.14 \\
= & 2.8.
\end{align}

Then apply $(*)$ for $k = 2$, we have
\begin{align}
& E[X^2] \\
= & 0^2 \times 0.26 + 1^2 \times 0.16 + 2^2 \times 0.12 + 3^2 \times 0.09 + 4^2 \times 0.07 + 5^2 \times 0.09 + 6^2 \times 0.07 + 7^2 \times 0.14 \\
= & 14.2.
\end{align}
Therefore, $\text{Var}[X] = E[X^2] - \{E[X]\}^2 = 14.2 - 2.8^2 = 6.36$.

Consequently, $\text{sd}[X] = \sqrt{\text{Var}[X]} = \sqrt{6.36} = 2.522$.

You can get more familiar with these stuff if you do more similar exercises.

Comment: I'm trying....mean = 0,125 ? How to calculate "variance", I'm really not familiar with these...

Comment: thank you. Why did you sum it like this "0 x 0.26 + 1 x 0.16 + 2 x 0.12", I mean "0, 1, 2, 3 x the value"

Comment: "Apply (*)", as I mentioned in the answer.